# how to verify credit card details without a payment gateway

Tags: php, validation

I'm building a small site that will collect credit card details from customers and store them, but not charge the cards - the transaction will be done by the client manually.

What I'd like to be able to do is check the numbers to make sure the card exists, and if possible, check if it is chargeable (i.e no dice for a zero or negative balance - this isn't required, but would be nice).

Are there any trustworthy (and preferably free to use) card verification web services out there?

Notes:

- Google-fu doesn't seem to cut it, most of my results return
  *validation* libraries rather than anything that will verify that the card numbers actually *exist*
- The site has SSL and all sensitive data is encrypted before storage (with salt). Security
  is outside the scope of this question but any observations or suggestions to improve it are welcome.

Comment: Storing credit card data is usually a **bad** idea. If they are compromised you are in big trouble.

Comment: You should use a payment gateway and authorize at the site and capture later. Storing credit card details is a bad idea

Comment: Isn't it illegal too? In some countries, like where I'm from, this isn't allowed by law.

Comment: Don't store credit card details. I can't say this enough!

Comment: As far as I am aware, it's impossible to verify the credit card details unless you use some gateway or service. As for storing the details, it's not illegal (as far as I am aware) but you must be PCI compliant and be insured for a LOT of money ;)

Comment: @Gavin You are absolutely right - it's the PCI compliance I was thinking about.

Comment: Curiously, the PCI DSS rules try to give the card schemes the right to issue punitive fines for non-compliance, which is itself illegal in UK law.

Comment: Yep I know it's not a good idea generally speaking. I don't exactly *want* to do it either - I'd rather use a gateway myself. With regards to legality, as far as I'm aware it's legal to do this in the UK so long as you don't store anything in plain text, it all has to be encrypted, and it has to be behind a login of some description (i.e password on your sql server). I could be wrong and I am checking up on this now, hence this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions of legality or whether you should do this aside, I'm fairly certain such a service does not exist, certainly not a free one.

In order to determine if a card exists or is chargeable a transaction has to be completed against the card. Normally for a 'validation' check this would take the form of a very small 'preauthorization' transaction, which requires a clearing bank, connections to credit card providers and all manner of expensive things.

If your client has the ability to process credit card transactions, he may be able to get you set up with what ever online tools his merchant bank / auth gateway has.

Comment: good answer, thanks. I'd also like to mention this for anyone else who happens on this question and wants to know more about the legal side - PCI DSS compliance covers you fairly well, read more here: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php

Answer (score 1):

Bulk is correct. The preferred way to do this is to validate and charge with the same party.

However, other options exist, for example going through third party companies (including [AllCharge](http://www.newgenpay.com/) and [CredoRax](http://credorax.com/)), which currently provide these services for a wide variety of cards around the world. Usually verification is free if there is a also transaction. If it's just the verification, fees are generally up to 20 cents, depending on the company.

It's also important to note that regarding legality, even if you're not completing an actual transaction with the cards, you're still required to be PCI compliant, since you would be *handling* the cardholder information.